# How to get into a variable only a part of the entered in EditText?

Tags: java, android, mobile

How to get into a variable in Java only part of the text or numbers entered in EditText (android). For example, from the entered number 123456789 to get only the first three digits 123?

Looked on the Internet but didnt find anything sensible

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substring method to get the number of characters you want:

```
String num = editText.toString().substring(0,3); //<-- gets the first 3 
                                                    characters of input
```

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-substring

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    if (editText.getText().toString().length() >= 2){
       String slice = editText.getText().toString().substring(0,2);
    } else {
        slice = editText.getText().toString();
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "slice = " + slice);
```

With this code, you can get first three digit or if editText has less numbers, you get max digits.

Examples:
https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/library/string/substring

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).